# Access token not found in the response error in Postman

Tags: postman, access-token

I'm trying to get my new access token with Postman for my application but I get this error in the response:

[image]

Can someone help me with this?

When I send the request for a new token I sent the request with the physical certificate and with all the fields completed secret id, client id and so on, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You must have sent something wrong, or used the wrong URL's as you are getting an HTML response (probably an error page) instead of a JSON response with the token.  Which Postman is then quite rightly telling your that the access_token is not found in the response.